# Radiant extensions on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, content-management-system

Anyone have any experience yet getting Radiant CMS extensions to actually make it onto a heroku instance?  I have tried removing the submodules and adding the files back, but haven't really had much luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku doesn't currently support git submodules.
However, their (excellent) documentation expresses a way around this: [check it out here](http://docs.heroku.com/constraints#git-submodules)

From the docs:

```
$ cd myapp
$ rm -rf `find . -mindepth 2 -name .git`
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "brought submodules into the main repo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Git submodules are not currently supported. We’re evaluating whether or not to support them in the future; in the meantime you’ll need to track any submodules in the main project. You can do so like this:

```
$ cd myapp
$ rm -rf `find . -mindepth 2 -name .git`
$ git rm --cache `git submodule | cut -f2 -d' '`
$ git rm .gitmodules
$ git add .
$ git config -l | grep '^submodule' | cut -d'=' -f1 | xargs -n1 git config --unset-all
$ git commit -m "brought submodules into the main repo"
```

Run this command if you’re not sure whether your project uses submodules:

```
$ find . -mindepth 2 -name .git
```

If it prints any output, you have submodules.