# How do you install Radiant extensions for Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, radiant

I havn't really found anything that works yet. I understand that Heroku does not allow submodules/extensions, so in order to install them, one needs to do something alternative.

My example is the Radiant Mailer. Normally to install this, I performed this :

```
./script/extension install mailer
```

What would be the alternative to make this work on Heroku?

[I have tried this already.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894647/radiant-extensions-on-heroku)

I've noticed that my problem persists because even though I `rm`'d and `wget`'d it back, `git status` still doesn't acknowledge that it exists there. Strange..

Comment: I always follow the process linked to and it's always worked for me.

Comment: @John, my problem was the naming convention for the folder, and also a little git confusion. But ultimately the link was the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so this is the best way I've found. Feel free to prove me wrong :

Manually install your extensions like so :

```
cd /path/to/radiant/vendor/extensions
wget http://github.com/saturnflyer/radiant-help-extension/tarball/master
tar xzvf saturnflyer-radiant-help-extension-*.tar.gz
mv saturnflyer-radiant-help-extension-* help
cd /path/to/radiant
rake radiant:extensions:help:migrate
rake radiant:extensions:help:update
```

The special note here and what was missing from my question's referred link was this :

If you used Radiant’s built-in `./script/extension install` command or Ray you can ignore this section as it only applies to manual installation.

In order to correctly load extensions, Radiant needs the extension’s directory name to match the extension’s (class) name.

The matching rule is the standard Rails camelcase <→ snakecase rule. For example, for an extension called “Foo” the extension directory name must be named “foo”. And for an extension named “FooBar”, the directory name must be “foo_bar”. If you fail to follow this convention, Radiant will fail to load the extension and the application won’t start. You’ll get an error when migrating the database like:

```
Could not load extension from file: some_extension.
#<NameError: uninitialized constant SomeExtension>
```

How to know an extension’s real name? For that look inside the extension directory for a file whose name ends in “_extension.rb”. That’s the extension’s main load file. The extension’s real name is the name before that ending. In the previous examples, that file would be called “foo_extension.rb” and “foo_bar_extension.rb” respectively.